# How to get a month prior date from a given date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a month dates from the `@EndDate` including provided date (`@EndDate`) in SQ Server 2008.

`@NoOfMonths` is a variable which decides how much previous months dates we need.
e.g.

```
@EndDate = 2020-07-28
@NoOfMonths = 6
```

Expected result would be:

```
2020-07-28
2020-06-28
2020-05-28
2020-04-28
2020-03-28
2020-02-28
```

I am trying using below recursive CTE query, however the results are not expected, I am getting month end dates.

```
@EndDate:  2020-07-28
@NoOfMonths = 6
```

Result:

```
2020-07-31
2020-06-30
2020-05-31
2020-04-30
2020-03-31
2020-02-29
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = CAST('2020 - 07 - 28' AS DATE);
DECLARE @NoOfMonths INT = 6;    

WITH CTE_previousMonths AS 
(
    SELECT   
        CAST(DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, -1, @EndDate), 0)) AS DATE) AS MonthPriorDate,
        1 AS months
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   
        CAST(DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, MonthPriorDate), 0)) AS DATE) AS MonthPriorDate,
        months + 1 AS months
    FROM     
        CTE_previousMonths
    WHERE    
        months < @NoOfMonths
)
SELECT CTE_previousMonths.MonthPriorDate
FROM CTE_previousMonths;
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over a year now, and you should really consider upgrading sooner rather than later.

Comment: What results do you expect for `@EndDate = 2020-03-30` and `@NoOfMonths = 2`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do what you want:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n < @NoOfMonths
     )
select dateadd(month, 1 - n, @enddate)
from n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Eomonth function:

```
WITH cte1 as
    (
    select EOMONTH('2020-07-28') as last_date, DATEADD(MONTH, -5, EOMONTH('2020-07-28')) AS END_DATE--Number of months - 1
    union all
    select DATEADD(MONTH, -1, last_date), END_DATE FROM CTE1 WHERE LAST_DATE > END_DATE
    )
    SELECT last_date FROM cte1;
```

Comment: The OP says: "I am trying using below recursive CTE query, however the results are not expected, I am getting month end dates." How does using `EoMonth` avoid getting "month end dates"?